# Can not connect to secure phpmyadmin through my c# code

Tags: c#, mysql, digital-ocean

I can not open a new connection through my code to my digitalocean server.. It's my first account and will be my first online database program.. here's what I did
after creating an account on digitalocean I've created a droplet and installed LAMP and secure phpmyadmin by following the installation tutorials..

I've given an IPv4 Address: xx.xxx.xx.xxx

when I typein  xx.xxx.xx.xxx/phpmyadmin to my browser it asks for username and password, than comes the phpmyadmin screen which asks for username root and it's password

I've created a new database= TestApp and users table..

and then I made a very basic program via c#, I have a textbox and a button and the code is as follows:

```
string conString = "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx;Database=TestApp;Uid=root;pwd=_______";
        MySqlConnection newCon = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO TestApp.users(isim) VALUES (?isim)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertCommand, newCon);
        newCon.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("?isim", txtpost.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        newCon.Close();
```

when I run the program it gives the following error:

An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

how do I solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know DigitalOcean, but I am assuming that the virual server has been configured to only allow web traffic into it (i.e. ports 80 and 443, which is why phpmyadmin works).

Your C# code (is it's not on the server itself) will need to access the MySQL port which by default is 3306.  You will need to find instructions on DigitalOcean for opening this up.

Comment: I added port=3306 to the connection string and it still didn't work, still gives the same error and it says: unable to connect because the targetted machine actively refused it

Comment: It's no good telling the client the port, it's the server that needs to allow it through. Your VM that's running MySQL needs to permit connections on that port.